# Erasure of method getTO(List<PdvdetMessage>) is the same as another method in type PdvdetTO

Tags: java, eclipse, método, ejb

Tengo problemas en Eclipse Oxygen, ya que me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error en los dos metodos: "Erasure of method getTO(List) is the same as another method in type PdvdetTO"

Lo cual se me hace raro, ya que como se puede observar, los dos metodos de arriba estan practicamente igual "getTO", y no marcan error. Obviamente si le cambio el nombre a uno de los dos, dejaran de marcar error...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es por la `clase`, las de arriba son diferentes mientra que en las siguientes usas `List` para ambos, lo cual lo interpreta que `List<> getTo()` es el mismo metodo y tipo

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [help], [faq] y [ask]. En concreto, por favor pon tu código (la parte relevante) en la pregunta como texto, no como captura de pantalla.